# Tortoise Svn shows all Unmodified files as Modified

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I am using Tortoise SVN and Visual SVN Server.

Here is how I am using SVN:

1. Export Code from Windows7 System and then Copy all code Files to my Fedora System
2. Make required changes.
3. Then I Checkout on Windows7 System.
4. Then Copy All code files from Fedora System to windows7 system.
5. Then paste in Folder where I checked out.

At this point when I check for modified files. SVN shows me all files as modified, even though they are not modified by me.

Also when I diff unmodified files by me no change is shown, but svn shows that file with red icon.

Could someone please explain the solution this issue?

Note: On Fedora System I am using QT Creator to edit code files. This issue observed with .txt, .cpp, .c files only not with qt ui files.

Comment: What is actually modified (I’m guessing Windows vs. Unix line endings? Or permission flags)? Why don’t you create a independent checkout on the Fedora system instead of this messy back-and-forth copying?

Comment: i m using fedora 10 and it does not have any gui based svn client.

Comment: can anyone suggest how can i solve issue of line endings or disable this line ending feature in tortoise svn

Answer (score 1):

You can find [here](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#detectmodification) how TortoiseSVN finds out if a file is modified.
You should look at the file metadata (date of creation/modification, ownership, etc.)

Edit: If you have issues with end-of-line markers, you can modify SVN behaviour with the [svn:eol-style](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.eol-style) property. See [this page](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html) for Tortoise configuration.